# Using ActionBarSherlock With Subclass of SupportMapFragment Inside Tabbed Navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-maps

Please see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721929/using-actionbarsherlock-with-the-new-supportmapfragment) for details on how it works.

**Current Setup**

I have created a class called `SherlockMapFragment` inside the `ActionBarSherlock`(ABS) library which extends `SupportMapFragment`. This works fine to display the map etc and I didn't realise until now (because I'm an idiot) the following:

- I created an instance of SherlockMapFragment called mapFrag.
- Then to use and display this I call mapFrag.newInstance().

What this is actually doing is returning an instance of SupportMapFragment however this call is necessary to get the MapView displayed.

This is a huge problem for what I am trying to achieve because I am trying to add my Fragments into a tabbed navigation bar but obviously I cannot add a `SupportMapFragment` to a TabListener because I get all sorts of class cast exceptions etc as its expecting an extension of `SherlockFragment` or `Fragment`.

Can anyone see a way round this? Or if I need to make myself clearer please just ask the question.

**One Possible Solution**

One solution is to create my own tab bar and handle the transaction of `Fragments` myself. However, the tools are already there and I don't really want to be doing this if its a simple fix.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extends SherlockFragment and handle the MapView yourself. This would look something like...

```
public class SherlockMapFragment extends SherlockFragment
{
private MapView mapView;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mapView = (MapView) getView().findViewById(R.id.my_map_id);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory()
{
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Nothing says you absolutely MUST use SupportMapFragment. One of the coolest parts of the new API is the ability to use the MapView as a normal View.

Comment: I am trying to insert just the MapView by including it in my xml layout however I do not know which class to cast it to as I keep getting `ClassCastException`. Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803385/android-google-maps-api-v2-0-including-mapview-in-xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this

public class BysFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Mapa 1")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<BySMapFragment>(this, "mapa", BySMapFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Mapa 2")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<BySMapFragment>(this, "mapa", BySMapFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
}

public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {    
        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

}
```

}