# Android Google Maps API V2.0 - Including MapView in XML

Tags: android, android-maps

I am trying to insert a MapView into a Fragment however I can't find the correct class to cast the `MapView` object to.

I am inserting the `MapView` into my fragment like so.

```
<com.google.android.gms.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map_view_track"/>
```

However, I inevitably get a `ClassCastException`.

Is it possible to insert a `MapView` this way? I'm pretty sure it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`com.google.android.gms.Maps` does not exist as a class, AFAIK. Try `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`.

Comment: Yet again you come to the rescue. I also have your book and find it immensely useful. Thanks

Comment: @DiscoS2: Could you post your stack trace? And I am glad that you like the book.

Comment: Problem solved. It was just a case of finding the correct class. I was just using `com.google.android.gms.MapView` or `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`