# ActionBar Sherlock with google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, actionbarsherlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using ActionBarSherlock With the New SupportMapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721929/using-actionbarsherlock-with-the-new-supportmapfragment)

sorry for the noob question, but I would like to know if there is a way to use the actionBar sherlok with google maps?
The thing here is that action bar needs to extends SherlockActivity but maps needs to extend MapActivity. are there other options to have an actionBar over a map?

any information would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is a possible duplication of stackoverflow.com/questions/13721929/using-actionbarsherlock-with-the-new-supportmapfragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use fragments. There you have a `MapFragment` to use: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html

or:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

Comment: do you know if MapFragment will be compatible with older version like 2.1 using android-support-v4.jar? there is no information about this on the documentation

Comment: good point. I don't think so :(

Comment: How about `SupportMapFragment`?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

Comment: I took a look at the SupportMapFragment and it's seems to be compatible backward. so I'm trying with it. thanks for pointing me

Answer (score 1):

You can do the map into a webView

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3