# Google Maps Android v2 not working with ActionBarSherlock Fragment Activity

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock, google-maps-android-api-2

I've followed the steps on [Using ActionBarSherlock With the New SupportMapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721929/using-actionbarsherlock-with-the-new-supportmapfragment) to use the new Google Maps Android v2 API, but I'm getting some errors that is causing the application to crash on startup.

I'm using Maven on my application, so I'm posting my AndroidManifest and POM files too.

Can you help me please?

Here's the error from logcat:

> 12-22 14:35:41.319: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
>           at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:269)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
>           at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
>           at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
>           at br.com.myapp.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="br.com.myapp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="2.0.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"></uses-sdk>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<permission android:name="br.com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="br.com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/rp_icon"
             android:logo="@drawable/logo_actionbar" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MyKeyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />

    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
    </manifest>
```

POM.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    br.com.myapp
    myapp-android
    2.0.0
    apk
    myapp

```
<properties>
    <platform.version>4.2
        </platform.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.loopj.android.http</groupId>
        <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <version>4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>10</platform>
                </sdk>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you include the full source from the Google Maps library? There are resources there (hence the reference to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)).

It's not enough to just reference the google-play-services.jar file. Double check the README.txt file at the root of the Google Play Services project.

Comment: I've switched from Android 4.2 Platform to Android Google 4.2 APIs on my compiler and added the com.google.android.maps dependency to my POM.xml, but still the same error. The README file says "Make sure you import this Android library project into your IDE
and set this project as a dependency", then I assume I won't be able to reference it using Maven. Is this correct?

Comment: At the moment "library" type projects can not be referenced as simple .jar. So try to reference Play service lib project.

Comment: +Good spot. People often checks src/ and there's no source, just jar. Nobody checks res/ - they just copy .jar file. and res/ is required for the lib, so you need either copy res/ or add as library (better solution)

Comment: But how we can add res if we add jar as maven dep?

Comment: You apklib as maven dependency, not jar.

Answer (score 4):

Found same issue on my project.
Solution is to add 2 dependencies for *com.google.android.gms* both *apklib* and *jar* to maven build script:

```
    <!-- google-play-services. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <version>4</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <version>4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Also, dependency *com.google.android.maps* not needed for maps v2.