# Google Map Android API v2 getMap() error

Tags: java, android, android-maps-v2, mapfragment

Hi I'm trying to implement Google Maps display in my app using Google Map Android API v2, and I am trying to follow the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721929/using-actionbarsherlock-with-the-new-supportmapfragment).

Codes seem to be okay except when I tried this part:

```
public class MapFragment extends SherlockMapFragment {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle    savedInstanceState) {
    View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    mMap = getMap();
    return root;
    }
}
```

The getMap() gives an error, as it says method getMap() is undefined for the type MapFragment. What does this mean?

Comment: put more code of your  getMap();

Comment: there is no codes for getMap() because I'm just following the solution, am unsure where the getMap() method comes from either

Comment: use this Example http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/howto-actionbarsherlock-mapfragment-listfragment/ instead of you implemented.

Comment: Thanks will take a look at it and see how it goes, but would much prefer having a solution to my question instead of trying to re-write the entire implementation again as your example seems more confusing

Answer (score -1):

The `getMap()` method is part of the `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` class. Your `SherlockMapFragment` should be extending this in the first place so just using `getMap()` shoudl work properly but unless you're doing some actual extra customizations with the ActionBar in the MapFragment and not your FragmentActivity, you can just extend `SupportMapFragment` in the first place.