# SupportMapFragment or GoogleMap is null

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, supportmapfragment

Managed to get the codes error free, however upon launching, I somehow always get a null pointer exception at the line mMap = mapFrag.getMap();

Why is this so? Am I missing some imports or some steps? I am unsure if it's the SupportMapFragment or GoogleMap object that's causing the problem.

```
package com.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MapFragment extends SherlockMapFragment {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag= (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map);
        mMap = mapFrag.getMap(); //null pointer is here
        return root;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: This is part of the implementation based on the solution given in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721929/using-actionbarsherlock-with-the-new-supportmapfragment)

Comment: To be blunt, what are you trying to do here? You have a class named `MapFragment`, yet it does not have a map. Instead, your `MapFragment` is trying to access a *different* `MapFragment`, where you have no evidence that that other fragment exists yet, let alone is ready to give you a map.

Comment: I am trying to implement the solution as given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721929/using-actionbarsherlock-with-the-new-supportmapfragment

Comment: "This is part of the implementation based on the solution given in this question" -- no, it is not. For example, show me *anywhere* in the accepted answer where a fragment is trying to access another fragment.

Comment: I previously followed it exactly like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537196/google-map-android-api-v2-getmap-error) but I added the SupportMapFragment line because without it the getMap() is undefined, and I got this based on some other solutions out there. Unless you could help me with the question I posted in the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you do not need to use a custom `Fragment` subclass necessarily to use Maps V2. If your fragment is just purely a map, you can create the `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment` from the activity and configure it there.

You do not even need to create some sort of `SherlockMapFragment` to be able to have a map be part of an ActionBarSherlock-based app. The regular `SupportMapFragment` works just fine.

If you do want to have more business smarts in your fragment, *and* if you are using ActionBarSherlock, *and* the business logic in question needs to do things related to ActionBarSherlock (e.g., contribute action items to the action bar), *then* and only then do you need to worry about having some sort of `SherlockMapFragment`.

I can confirm that [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4392030) contains a working `SherlockMapFragment`. Note that it goes into the `com.actionbarsherlock.app` package, as it needs some package-protected access to the rest of ActionBarSherlock.

You can then subclass that, such as creating a `MyMapFragment`:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SherlockMapFragment {
  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (getMap() != null) {
      Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Map ready for use!");
    }
  }
}
```

You have to be a bit careful on the timing of calling `getMap()` -- too soon and it will return `null`. `onActivityCreated()` seems like a fairly safe time, though you are free to experiment.

Then, you just use `MyMapFragment` wherever you would have used `SupportMapFragment`:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.commonsware.android.mapsv2.sherlock.MyMapFragment"/>
```

[Here is the complete project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Sherlock) containing the above code.

Comment: Thanks for this, perhaps you are right about the timing of calling getMap(). However as I've said, without the SupportMapFragment object, I am unable to call the getMap() method on its own?

Comment: Ah nevermind, I realized I did a very stupid mistake of not extending SupportMapFragment class in SherlockMapFragment which caused the problem! Thank you for the example =)

Comment: Thank you so much for the Maps v2 Sherlock project! It helped me a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of implementing an extra class such as SherlockMapFragment. You can handle the SupportMapFragment inside of the Fragment or the SherlockFragment class code. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17803561/1755300).