# How to show google map v2 in Fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i have frame layout, where i show fragments, how i can show google map it that frame_layout. I make next:

1. Get Api Key
2. add google play services library
   But i get nullPointerExeption, maybe someone knows good examples how to use it?
   car_waches.xml

Fragment class:

```
public class FragmentCarWashes extends SherlockFragment {
View v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment))
               .getMap();
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_washes, null);

    return v;
}
}
```

Manifet file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.cars51ru.permition.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.cars51ru.permition.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission       android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v3.API_KEY"
        android:value="api key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.cars51ru.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.cars51ru.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not well versed in the serlock stuff bu I believe you need to use `SherlockMapFragment`

Edit:

take a look at this link

[SupportMapFragment or GoogleMap is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539929/supportmapfragment-or-googlemap-is-null/17803651#17803651)