# getSupportFragmentManager() method is undefined for type MapFragment

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, supportmapfragment

I'm trying to implement Google Map display and below are my codes:

```
package com.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MapFragment extends SherlockMapFragment {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag= (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map);
        mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        return root;
    }
}
```

Im getting an error that getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for type MapFragment. However I'm a little confused as I have imported com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment. shouldn't this method come from there then? Am I missing out some steps in getting this method to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using this [SherlockMapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13727539/1267661), try:

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Though I'm abit confused why I have to get the SherlockActivity though.

But anyway now I'm getting another problem on nullpointer exception... [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539929/supportmapfragment-or-googlemap-is-null)

Comment: Because SherlockMapFragment is not a SherlockFragment, it's a SupportMapFragment (not part of ABS) that should be attached to a FragmentActivity... So it behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I spent last couple of hours reading this and other 2 of your questions (among others) because I was having exactly same issue. I had an app working ABS+GMapsV2.0+FragmentActivity, but since I hear a lot that it's a good practice to have it all in fragments, I started porting it to fragments and FragmentActivities as containers.

When I ported the map, happened exactly the same, getSupportFragmentManager() was not recognized, and I did not like quite much the proposed solution creating the SherlockMapFragment messing up the ABS library, so I kept digging.

Most likely you knew already at this point, but I just realize you (as well as me 10 minutes ago) were trying to handle a fragment that is defined in xml but is not created (indexed) yet.

Taking a look at [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) checking the order of calls in fragment methods, I tried the code in other method after onCreateView()... and changing getSupportFragmentManager() for getFragmentManager() or even following the solution given using getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() I could handle those fragments which already exist.

```
public class MapsFragment extends SherlockFragment {


private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;
private GoogleMap map;
private Marker spotAMarker;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment_test); //THIS ONE
    mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment_test); //OR THIS ONE
    if(mSupportMapFragment != null) {
        map = mSupportMapFragment.getMap(); 

        if(map != null) {

            spotAMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(4.651904,-74.057352)).
                    title(getString(R.string.spot_a_title)).snippet(getString(R.string.spot_a_subtitle)).
                    icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("images/spot_a.png")));
            spotAMarker.setDraggable(true);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), getString(R.string.no_map_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "No Map Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

May be you got already the workaround for the issue, but I wanted to share my experience with other stucked in same issue.

Comment: Is there any chance you have more information on this? Like what the XML looks like? Is this the only code you need to get it to work in a SherlockFragment? Not a lot out there for SherlockFragment and GoogleMaps.